# Anonimizar datos tomando el valor de la izquierda

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe como este:

```
BD_convert       BD_raw
    67              67
    46              46
    42              42
    53              53
    63              63
    63              63
    59              59
    52              52
    73              73
    60              60
    45              45
    70              70
    79              79
    91              91
    52              52
    63              63
    57              57
    57              57
    45              45
    85              85
    57              57
    83              83
    58              58
    74              74
    88              88
    54              54
```

A partir de este dataframe he intentado anonimizar los datos usando el siguiente comando:

Prueba <- globalRecode(Prueba, column = c('BD_raw'),
seq(0,130,5))

El cual obtengo un dataframe como este:

```
    BD_convert       BD_raw
    (65,70]             67
    (45,50]             46
    (40,45]             42
    (50,55]             53
    (60,65]             63
    (60,65]             63
    (55,60]             59
    (50,55]             52
    (70,75]             73
    (55,60]             60
    (40,45]             45
    (65,70]             70
    (75,80]             79
    (90,95]             91
    (50,55]             52
    (60,65]             63
    (55,60]             57
    (55,60]             57
    (40,45]             45
    (80,85]             85
    (55,60]             57
    (80,85]             83
    (55,60]             58
    (70,75]             74
    (85,90]             88
    (50,55]             54
```

El código ha funcionado a la hora de anonimizar las edades, el problema que no consigo solucionar es intentar anonimizar tomando el valor izquierdo y no el derecho, es decir [a,b) en vez de (a,b]

¿Cómo puedo realizarlo?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando el código de [`globalRecode()`](https://github.com/sdcTools/sdcMicro/blob/master/R/globalRecode.R) entiendo que no es posible hacerlo desde esta función, para construir los rangos se usa la función base `cut()` sin embargo no hay la posibilidad de configurar el parámetro `right=FALSE` que es lo que lograría hacer lo que buscas.

Para lo que buscas, tal vez te alcance con usar directamente `cut()`:

```
Prueba$BD_raw <- cut(Prueba$BD_raw, breaks = seq(0,130,5), right = FALSE)
```

Comment: Funciona y muy bien, muchas gracias Patricio